# How to validate data so no incorrect data is saved to the database, using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I would like to validate my code for adding a product to sqlite database, but dont know how I do that in the best way. I have been using this:

`routes.post('/product/', async (req, res)`

and await for adding a product to the sqlite database, which was successful. 
What I would like to accomplish is to check so the same product can't be added twice. Do you have any tips for how I can do that? 
I was thinking if I could use an if statement to check that..

Comment: Create a unique index would be step 1, however you probably want some client side checking too for a more user friendly way of giving feedback. How is impossible to say without some example what you have now and tried yourself.

Comment: It can be handled by SQLite, by creating a unique index for a column. That would make it so two rows in the database can't have the same value in that column. You could read up on indexes in SQLite here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/

Comment: Use ORM, e.g. sequelize.org

Answer (score 0):

When you create your sqlite table, add a statement something like this to create a unique index (an index that prohibits duplicate values) on your table.

You can also add this index onto an existing table.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX product_indx ON yourtable(product);
```

Then, attempts to insert duplicate values of `product` will fail and throw an error.

You can catch the error and use it to whine at your user, or present whatever error message is appropriate

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get all the product from the db inside `routes.post('/product/', async (req, res)` and compare it with the request